# Who of the patients has recovered? Which of the patients has recovered?

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns

> Who of the  patients has recovered?
>   Which of the patients has recovered?

Which one is correct?

> Who of the  patients has recovered?

I never ever heard such sort of sentence.
Would you like to differentiate between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of them are even grammatical in the first place.

> Who of patients has recovered?

is just plain awful. "who" does not connect to what group whoever recovered was in. That's "which"'s job.

A better version would be:

> Who has recovered?

The group of the people that have recovered from something (the patients) is inferred from context.

The following is better but needs the definite article due to the "patients" being countable.

> **Which** of *the* patients have recovered? (if specific patients were asked for)

or

> Which of the patients has recovered? (if you've heard of that one patient recovered)

This implies that out of a **group of patients mentioned earlier**, some of them have recovered (in the plural; so far), or in the singular, just one of them.

The answer is **neither** of them are correct as is.

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to put definite article. Well, you mean to say, both are correct. Right?

Comment: Both are incorrect. The answer shows you the correct ways to make your questions right.

Comment: What about "Which of the patients *have* recovered?"

Comment: @nnnnnn I was not being careful; I had changed part of the sentence but not everything affected by it. Corrected.

Comment: Depending on the context, the original usage of "has recovered" could be valid and more grammatical. For example, perhaps the speaker was informed that someone (i.e. one patient) had made a full recovery. In this case, "has recovered" is the correct form. The original post doesn't provide enough detail to distinguish the context, so it is worth noting that this element is not necessarily erroneous.